# Is it possible to create an MLlib RDD<LabeledPoint> from a double[][] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to play around with the Gradient Boosting and Random Forests in MLLib, just locally.

I have some data I want to pass into the learning algorithm that comes to me in the form of a two-dimensional array of doubles. First dimension dictates row, second column. I also get responses for each row in a single-dimensional array of doubles of the same length.

Surely there is a way to create an RDD from these variables so I can run the algorithms locally?

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do at the moment, though I hope there is a better way:

```
public static JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> makeMeAnRDD(double[][] X, double[] y, JavaSparkContext context)
{
    assert(X.length == y.length);

    List<LabeledPoint>  xList   = new LinkedList<LabeledPoint>();

    // ivec <=> row number.
    for (int ivec = 0; ivec < X.length; ivec++)
    {
        LabeledPoint    x       = new LabeledPoint(y[ivec], Vectors.dense(X[ivec]));
    }

    return context.parallelize(xList);
}
```